Migrating JSR 352 ItemWriter to Spring batch 5 ItemWriter
I have below code which is a JSR 352 batch job ItemWriter. I am migrating it to Spring Batch 5.
I could map open & close methods in target state (Available in ItemStreamWriter). However, I didn't find a way to migrate checkpointInfo() method. Any pointers?


import javax.batch.api.chunk.ItemWriter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomWriter.class.getCanonicalName());
    @Override
    public void open(Serializable checkpoint) throws Exception { 
        // some logic
        LOGGER.logp(Level.FINE, CustomWriter.class.getSimpleName(), "open()", "I am opening writing");
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception { 
        // some logic
        LOGGER.logp(Level.FINE, CustomWriter.class.getSimpleName(), "close ()", "I am closing down writing");
    }
    @Override
    public void writeItems(List<Object> items) throws Exception { 
        // some logic
        LOGGER.logp(Level.FINE, CustomWriter.class.getSimpleName(), "writeItens()",
                "I am writing this number of lines: " + items.size());
    }
    @Override
    public Serializable checkpointInfo() throws Exception {
        // some logic
        return "No op writer";
    }
}



